# Variadic templates deduction error

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I wrote a simple log function by c++0x variadic templates,
but there are templates deduction error,could somebody help me, thanks!

```
#ifndef SLOG_H
#define SLOG_H

enum LOGLEVEL{INFO, DEBUG, ERROR};
/* static */ const char* g_loglevel[] = {"INFO", "DEBUG", "ERROR"};

template <class T>
void slog_(const T& v) {
    std::cout << v;
}

template <class T, class... Args>
void slog_(const T& v, const Args&... args) {
    std::cout << v;
    slog_(args...);
}

template <class T, class... Args>
void slog(LOGLEVEL level, const Args&... args) {
    time_t t;
    struct tm tm;
    char buf[32];

    time(&t);
    localtime_r(&t, &tm);

    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%F %T", &tm);
    std::cout << "[" << g_loglevel[level] << "][" << buf << "] ";

    slog_(args...);
}

#endif
```

In call function:

```
slog(INFO, "hello, number ", n, ", next is ", n + 1);
```

then compile error:

```
main.cpp:6:53: error: no matching function for call to 'slog(LOGLEVEL, const char [15], int&, const char [11], int)'
main.cpp:6:53: note: candidate is:
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
slog.h:19:6: note: template<class T, class ... Args> void slog(LOGLEVEL, const Args& ...)
slog.h:19:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:6:53: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `template <class T, class... Args>` to `template <class... Args>` for `slog`. As the error message says: `couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'` because you never use it as a function parameter.

Comment: There are typically two patterns you will see: 1) A template and template specialization where one will handle a single argument (I prefer this as the specialization, but some versions of GCC have problems with that), and the other will peel off the first and have a variadic 'tail'. 2) If you want to isolate that logic (or have some policy to apply) you will often see a distinct template that only takes a variadic, as you have done in your code.